# PHP segfault on regexp under certain conditions, how should I report this?

Tags: php, regex, segmentation-fault, pcre

I had a script that was segfaulting. I reduced the case to the following:

```
// a very loooong string ---->
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent mauris nibh, fringilla dapibus pharetra sit amet, cursus ut elit. Proin nulla nisl, accumsan at vulputate eu, elementum ac enim. Aliquam tortor lacus, ullamcorper sed purus ac, pulvinar euismod sem. Praesent euismod lacus et . Proin nulla nisl, accumsan at vulputate eu, elementum ac enim. Aliquam tortor lacus, ullamcorper sed purus ac, pulvinar euismod sem. Praesent euismod lacus et . Proin nulla nisl, accumsan at vulputate eu, elementum ac enim. Aliquam tortor lacus, ullamcorper sed purus ac, pulvinar euismod sem. Praesent euismod lacus et . Proin nulla nisl, accumsan at vulputate eu, elementum ac enim. Aliquam tortor lacus, ullamcorper sed purus ac, pulvinar euismod sem. Praesent euismod lacus et";
preg_match_all('/^(.)*$/', $string, $matches);
```

This segfaults under these conditions:

It crashes on PHP5.3.x and PHP5.4.x on Windows and when using Apache.

It runs fine on Linux. It runs fine via command line (on Windows) and PHPUnit.

If you reduce the length of `$string` it will run fine. If you change the regexp to `/^(?:.)*$/` (non-capturing) it runs fine.

So my guess is that I'm hitting some kind of limit.

```
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000
```

Should I report this, if so, how/where?

---

I can easily make a workaround by changing the regexp so it's not that much of an issue for me. The segfaulting is just really annoying (hard to debug, hard to detect)

Comment: Why do you want every single character seperately matches? I think you hitting a limit.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, you can report it at https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: @Haneev That is what causes the segfault. I reduced this regexp from a more complex (and very poorly written) one. The triviality of the regexp shouldn't matter, it should not segfault.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Agreed. While it's easy to explain why PHP can't handle it (`$matches` grows _way_ too big), the way of "not being able to handle it" is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net/) to see if similar issues have been reported.  If not, make a bug report of your own.  It looks like you have a pretty good handle on how to reproduce the bug.